# Filter an array by multiple criteria using Sanity Groq

Tags: sanity

I'd like to return documents with cateogry arrays similar to the following

```
"category":[3 items
  0:"A"
  1:"B"
  2:"C"
]
```

Using a query that looks something like this

```
*[ "A" || "C" in category ]{
    }
```

The above will only recognize "C" in category and I'd like to dynamically update the criteria without having to spell out "in category" for each criteria. Not sure how to do this with sanity

Answer (score 1):

To filter for one or more array items in another array, you can use this syntax:

```
*[count((category)[@ in ['A', 'C']]) > 0]
```

It's somewhat of a workaround that lets you search for array items inside of an array. `count(...) > 0` behaves like `OR` while `count(...) == TOTAL_ITEM_COUNT` behaves like `AND`.